# How to force page to load from the top after window has been closed and then reopened

Tags: javascript, scroll, pageload, scroll-position

I'm running into an issue with my site where if I scroll halfway down the page, close the tab, then reopen it using Shift + Ctrl + T, the opened page loads at the same position it was at when I closed it. I'm already using Javascript to force the page to go to the top whenever it's refreshed, with this code:

`window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}`

And that's working fine for refreshing the page, but not when I close the tab then immediately reopen it. Not sure why. Is there a difference between refreshing a page and closing+immediately reopening it? Should I be using a different method for the second case?

Comment: I believe that the browser itself keeps closed tabs in a temporary cache during a browsing session. I don't believe there are any JS events associated with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use onload to catch the page when it loads back up again. You wouldn't need to use onbeforeunload at all either.

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing onbeforeunload with onload and a weird thing happened - now I load the page, and a second after I begin scrolling down, the page appears to refresh/go back to the top. Then when I scroll down again everything is normal. Maybe because I start scrolling before the page has loaded fully, so when it's finished loading a second or two after I scroll down, the onload function is triggered, forcing the page back to the top.

Comment: Also just noticed the page doesn't go back to the top on refresh, like it does when I use onbeforeunload.

Comment: @voidflaw That's odd. The other thing I would possibly try suggesting is using onunload, but it looks like you may have already tried that